# How to do binary search in a std::multiset without constructing a key_type object?

Tags: c++, stl, set, binary-search, multiset

I have a container like this:

```
// Sort functor
struct SortByTime :
  std::binary_function<const TimeSortableData &, const TimeSortableData &, bool>
{
    bool operator()(const TimeSortableData & a, const TimeSortableData & b) const
    {
        return a.GetTime() < b.GetTime();
    }
};

// Container that sorts by time
typedef std::multiset<TimeSortableData, SortByTime> TimeSortedData;
```

Now if I want to get the last data object before time `t`, I could create a dummy object and call `upper_bound()`:

```
TimeSortableData dummy(t);
TimeSortedData::const_iterator it = mySortedData.upper_bound(dummy);
--it;
// result = *it;
```

This gives me logarithmic search complexity.
Aside from looking clumsy, this approach is problematic if such a dummy object is very hard to create (not wrt. run-time performance but coding effort).

I've looked at `std::multiset::key_comp` but I don't see how I could use it..
Both `std::multiset::find()` and `std::binary_search()` want me to give them the container's `key_type`, i.e. `TimeSortableData` objects...

How can I search eficiently without having to create a dummy object?

**Update from comments:**
There is also `find_if()`: It would spare me the effort of creating a dummy object but at the price of O(n) complexity.

Comment: To search is to compare. To compare is to have something to compare with.

Comment: @sbi I believe, I have something to compare. I want to compare time `t` with the result of `GetTime()`.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Maybe you could do this using `std::find_if()`?

Comment: @sbi It looked interesting at first but I'm afraid that `find_if()` has linear complexity. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/)

Comment: Yeah, you wanted logarithmic. I forgot about that. Sorry for all the noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that if your keys are so expensive to construct that you worry about creating a temporary dummy key, you can always change your code to use an `std::multimap` instead.  Let the key be something cheap to construct, such as an integer or `time_t` or whatever `GetTime()` returns, and then the `data_type` could be the larger data.

```
typedef std::multimap<time_t, TimeSortableData> TimeSortedData;
TimeSortedData mySortedData;

...

time_t dummy = [whatever];
TimeSortedData::const_iterator it = mySortedData.upper_bound(dummy);
if (it != mySortedData.begin()) --it; // Check that iterator isn't at beginning
result = it->second;
```

Comment: I guess my first comment was a bit too early... Changing the container type breaks a lot of existing code and is impractical in my situation.

Comment: However, your suggestion appears to be the Right Thing to do. I'll accept it as answer but continue to use the crutch of constructing dummy objects...